# How to get the number of records from table 1 based on table 2 total count

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table1

```
Rowno   name         Date
------------------------------------
1     sathish        Dec 21    
2     kumar          Dec 22
3     sathish        Dec 21
4     sathish        Dec 22
5     sathish        Dec 21
5     sathish        Dec 22
```

Table 2

```
Date          NoofTran
-----------------------
Dec22            2
Dec21            1
```

I want to get the records from `table1` based on the `table2` `nooftran` values and randomly.

On Dec21st, there are 3 records and no of records to display is 2 and it should take it from randomly.

What SQL query should I use?

Comment: Provide your SQL Query

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. Add expected result, and perhaps I'll understand the problem.

Comment: On dec21st, nooftran should take it is 2, so two records should take it from table 1 and it should be random case.
so rownum 1 and 3 or 5 would come

Comment: On dec21st, the number of transaction is 2 in table 2, so two records should take it from table 1 and it should be random case. so rownum 1 and 3 or 5 would come

Comment: Also what do you mean randomly? You don't care which 2 lines(meaning a solution that brings the first two lines every time is OK), or you want 2 out of the 3 but every time 2 different lines, so when you refresh, you mostly see different values?

Comment: I dont have any idea how to work on this, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just join both the tables and order by the NoofTran

```
select Table1.*
from Table1 T1
inner join Table2 T2
on T1.[Date] = T2.[Date]
order by T2.NoofTran DESC
```

This will give you the result in NoofTran order

Comment: This is not the correct query which i want...in the Table 2, For Dec 22nd, the noofTrans is 2 so only two records fetch it from table 1 and randomly i.e out of 3 any two should come for that particular date

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH CTE  AS (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (
            PARTITION BY T1.Date 
            order by NEWID()
        ) AS RN 
        FROM Table1 T1
    )
    SELECT CTE.RowNo,CTE.Date, CTE.Name
    FROM CTE INNER JOIN Table2 T2 
    ON T2.date=cte.Date
    WHERE RN <= T2.NoofTran
```